# Read Dsn in the registry without admin rights in Win7

Tags: c#, vb.net

In win7, I need to read some dns in the registry, but without admin rights.

How can I do this in Vb.Net or c# ?

The dsn are in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI and

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ODBC\ODBC.INI

Thank you in advance

p.s. I use this code, but doesn't work

```
        Dim registryKey As RegistryKey
    Dim registrySubKey As RegistryKey

    Try

        registryKey = Registry.LocalMachine
        registrySubKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(sString, True)

        SourceRegInfo.Add(New Model_DatiRegestry() With _
        { _
            .DataBase = registrySubKey.GetValue("DataBase"), _
            .Description = registrySubKey.GetValue("Description"), _
            .Server = registrySubKey.GetValue("Server")
        })

        registrySubKey.Close()
        registryKey.Close()

        GetValueDns = True

    Catch ex As Exception
        GetValueDns = False
        MessageBox.Show(Err.Description, "GetValueDns !!", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information)
    End Try
```

**Solved..!!! This code is Ok...**

```
    Dim PathFind As String = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\" ' bla bla bla


        Dim sDataBase = My.Computer.Registry.GetValue(PathFind + sString, "DataBase", Nothing)
        Dim sDescription = My.Computer.Registry.GetValue(PathFind + sString, "Description", Nothing)
        Dim sServer = My.Computer.Registry.GetValue(PathFind + sString, "Server", Nothing)
        SourceRegInfo.Add(New Model_DatiRegestry() With _
        { _
            .DataBase = sDataBase, _
            .Description = sDescription, _
            .Server = sServer
        })

        GetValueDns = True
```

Comment: What have you tried thus far? Have you already tried it without administrative rights? If so, what error did you receive, if any? Have you compared it to when the program *does* have administrative rights? Do you have any code?

Comment: Yes, I have already tried it without administrative rights whith error message: 
**Requested registry access is not allowed**

Comment: Then I'd assume you can't read from it.

Comment: Include any code you have in the question itself, not the comments area.